# C# dynamically set property When Property is a class?

Tags: c#, reflection

Hi i have a Number of Properties and My properties like

```
public XYZ()
{
    xyz = new xyz1();
    xyz2 = new xyz2();
}
public xyz1 xyz1 { get; set; }
public xyz2 xyz2 { get; set; }
}

public class xyz1
{
    public string fName { get; set; }
    public string lnameget; set;}
}
public class xyz2
{
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state
}
```

While i am setting my property on runtime i am getting exception object reference set to null.

```
XYZ model = new XYZ();
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = model.GetType().GetProperty("fName");
propertyInfo.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(item.InnerText, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```

Please help me

Comment: XYZ has no fName property.

Comment: Then how can i set navigational property value

Comment: Can you just set `model.xyz1.fName` directly? Why use `PropertyInfo`?

Comment: Because its happening in run time and i don't know about model on runtime that's why

Comment: In that case you will need to get the `xyz1` property of `model` and **then** the `fName` property of `xyz1`. Or use `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

model has no fName property, but model.xyz1 does.

Comment: Yeah But i am getting exception while using this code -> PropertyInfo propertyInfo = model.GetType().GetProperty("fName");
                                propertyInfo.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(item.InnerText, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);